# What does this code mean (if v then return v end)?

Tags: lua, memoization

So I have this piece of code and it is this:

```
do 

    local function index(n,m)
        return n*(n+1)//2 + m
    end

    local binomtable = {}

    function binom3(n,m)
        if n<0 or m<0 or m>n then return 0 end
        if n=0 or m=0 or m=n then return 1 end
        local i = index(n,m)
        local v = binomtable[i]
        if v then return v end
        v = binom3(n-1,m-1) + binom3(n-1,m)
        binomtable[i] = v
        return v
    end

end
```

and I would like to know what

```
if v then return v end
```

means.

Thank you!

Comment: `if v~=nil then return v end`

Comment: `if v~=nil and v~=false then return v end`

Comment: if it has already calculated a value for binomtable[i], then it returns that value, otherwise, it'll continue with the script, and generate a value for that table position.

Comment: You got an accepted answer. So I undo the "test question" edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is that `if v then return v end` returns the value `v` if it is truthy, i.e., if it is neither `false` nor `nil`. Otherwise the function continues by calculating a value for `v`, storing that value in `binomtable`, and finally returning it. The more interesting question is, why is the function doing all of this?

In the posted code, `binom3` is a recursive function. With the recursive calls `v = binom3(n-1,m-1) + binom3(n-1,m)` there will be a lot of duplication of effort, meaning a lot of wasted space and time. Consider:

```
binom3(4, 2)
--> binom3(3, 1) + binom3(3, 2)
--> binom3(2, 0) + binom3(2, 1) + binom3(2, 1) + binom3(2, 2)
--> 1 + binom3(1, 0) + binom3(1, 1) + binom3(1, 0) + binom3(1, 1) + 1
```

Note how in the second reduction there are two identical terms:

```
binom3(2, 1) + binom3(2, 1)
```

There is no reason to calculate the term `binom3(2, 1)` twice, and doing so means that the pair of terms:

```
binom3(1, 0) + binom3(1, 1)
```

also must be calculated twice, as seen in the third reduction. It would be smart to calculate `binom3(2, 1)` only once, and to save the result for later use in the larger calculation. When `m` and `n` are larger and the number of calculations explodes exponentially this becomes a very important issue for performance both in the amount of memory required and in the amount of time required.

The posted code is using [*memoization*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) to improve performance. When a calculation is made, it is stored in the table `binomtable`. Before any calculation is made, `binomtable` is consulted. First, `v` is set to the value of `binomtable[i]`; if this value is any truthy value (any integer is a truthy in Lua), then that value is simply returned without the need for recursive calculation. Otherwise, if `nil` is returned (i.e., no value has yet been stored for the calculation), the function continues with a recursive calculation. After completing the calculation, the new value is stored in `binomtable` for use the next time it is needed. This strategy saves a lot of wasted computational effort, and can make a huge difference in the performance of such recursive algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

For your specific question of what

```
if v then return v end
```

means, is that if `v`, a variable, is not `nil` or `false` it is to return the value of the v variable and stop executing that function.

```lua
--Similar
function myfunc(input)
  local MyVar = "I am a string and am not nil!"
  if MyVar then
    return "hi"
  else
    return "hello"
  end

  print("I am not seen because I am unreachable code!")
end
```

if this function was called it would always return "hi" instead of "hello" because MyVar is true, because it has a value. Also the `print` function below that will never get called because it stops executing the function after a `return` is called.

Now for your codes case it is checking a `table` to see if it has an entry at a certain `index` and if it does it returns the value.